# What are the standard bio-safety protocols for preparing plant pathology herbarium specimina?

Tags: botany, safety

What are the standard bio-safety protocols for preparing plant pathology herbarium specimina?

I searched google but I did not found anything relevant, nor in my textbooks. I want to know about what bio-safety precautions must be taken before preparing plant pathology herbarium specimena.

PS. It seems many teachers and students routinely prepare herbarium specimens of wild and agricultural specimens including notoriously contagious fungal plant pathogens, but they are basically pressing and drying the sample in classroom notebooks and pasting it on herbarium sheets just like ordinary herbarium specimen. Sometimes old and neglected herbarium specimens go into ordinary garbage or stray official papers.

But whenever I ask a question about it, nobody could yet mention references or protocols (I put apart the authoritative issue), sometimes they give vague reasons with buzzwords like the pathogenicity will reduce with time, or the "disease triangle" (optimal conditions) are unlikely to occur, etc.

I kindly request to provide me protocols and references about safe way for preparing plant pathology herbarium specimens